# php mailer function with multiple attachment

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a form which has a value `count`. I want to send mail with attachment and the attachment is as many time the `count` value is. Actually I want to send the attachment checking some factors by `if` statement, so how can I do this, please can any one help me for this?
Here my code goes:

```
<?php
echo $count;
require_once 'session.php';
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
$body = file_get_contents('mail.html');
$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
$mail->AddReplyTo("lipsa.auroin@gmail.com","First Last");
$mail->SetFrom('lipsa.auroin@gmail.com', 'First Last');
$mail->AddReplyTo("lipsa.auroin@gmail.com","First Last");
$email=$_POST['email2'];
$addresses = explode(',', $email);
foreach ($addresses as $address){
    $address = trim($address);
    $mail->AddAddress($address);
}
$mail->Subject = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAttachment("pdf/report.pdf");
$mail->AddAttachment("pdf/template.pdf");
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

I have the `count` variable with value starting from 1 to n

Answer (score 0):

Where are stored the attachments?
Sorry but i can't find it in your code.
Why aren't you just putting them in an array and then loop them?

Something like:

```
foreach($attachments as $attachment){
  $mail->AddAttachment($attachment);
}
```

If this is not what you need to know just tell me more about where are stored this attachments and i'll help further.